# Liferay Setup with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, liferay-6

I am new to liferay. I have Liferay Tomcat bundle. Now I want to connect liferay portal with NoSql database(mongodb or dynamodb). Please tell me the steps to connect liferay portal with mongodb.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can not shift from RDBMS to totally on Nosql database.

Because Liferay store permissions and also other metadata related stuff in RDBMS but 
You can store all the content and data to mongodb for faster access and also scalability.

Your custom portlet data also can be stored to mongodb but you have to write your own service layer by using mongo driver.

This is not enough space to provide all detail but Provided link below could give some shadow on it and how to proceed futher.

[Lifera+mongoDB](http://www.cignex.com/blog/building-big-data-portal-through-liferay-and-mongodb-integration)